# How do I set a variable in an Impala query using HUE?

Tags: impala

I need to add parameters in several locations in a long query. I want to use parameters because I need to run the query multiple times with different values substituted in. This is very cumbersome because I need to replace the text in all locations whenever I need to change my filter criteria. Is there a way to set a variable in Impala via HUE?

Initial research indicates that this is possible when working with the impala-shell but for HUE, I've found nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image] You can set variables in Impala via HUE as you can see in the following picture

Comment: This works and it also accommodates multiple values (e.g. - Monopoly','Scrabble) for use with the 'in' operator. Thank you.

Comment: It was useful and you can upvote, I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Line 2 `SET game;` for me results in `ParseExceptopm: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: SET game ^ Encountered: EOF Expected: = CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error.` If I try to set a value, e.g. `SET game=10;`, I get `Invalid query option: game`.
Is there some special setting in Hue or Impala needed for this `SET` syntax to work?

Comment: Hi @RyanJendoubi You can remove 'SET game' The variable is set when you type: '${var_name}' in the editor in the WHERE clause. For instance: SELECT field1, field2 FROM table_name WHERE field3 = '${var_name}'; and you can set the var value below the query as you can see in the picture example. I hope this will solve your doubts.

Comment: I have removed the former picture. It was confusing.

Comment: Thank you @Chema for clarifying 

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this script. Here type of variables int and date.
Also can define a default value.

```
SELECT id, fullname, birthdate 
FROM db.scientists
WHERE id <= ${id=2} 
AND to_date(birthdate) BETWEEN '${mindate=1900-01-01}' AND '${maxdate=2000-01-01}'
```

[image]